# WebAudio: total oscillator count and performance (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, performance, web-audio-api

I'm creating lots of these sort of WebAudio instrument-objects:

```
var context = new AudioContext();

Inst = function (id, param){
  var inst = {
    id = id,
    param = param
  }
  inst.osc = context.createOscillator();
  inst.gain = context.createGain();
  inst.osc.connect(inst.gain);
  inst.gain.connect(context.destination)
  inst.gain.gain.value = 0;
  inst.osc.start();

  inst.playTone = function () {
    inst.gain.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.1);        
  } 
  inst.stopTone = function () {
    inst.gain.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.1);        
  }     
instList[id] = inst;    
}
```

As you can see, I'm just raising and lowering the volume. Using `.start()` and `.stop()` in the `inst.` functions is problematic because `.stop` kills the oscillator, and the user will be interacting repeatedly with these objects.

I'm wondering, is there a maximum number of oscillators that can be handled in the AudioContext? Is there some potential performance issue if I start a whole bunch of oscillators and never stop them?

(Side note: If it's a recommended approach, I'm open to suggestions of how to dynamically create a new oscillators each time... I haven't figured that out yet, and after all I'm not sure it's needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of oscillators you can effectively use is limited only by how powerful your machine is.  A low-powered machine can only support a few simultaneous oscillators before glitching.  A high-powered machine can handle many more.

You don't want to leave oscillators running forever because they will burn up all the CPU available.

Since you have the gain go to zero after some time, what you can do is schedule the oscillator to stop after the gain goes to zero.  A general rule of thumb is to use 5-10 times the time constant you used in `setTargetAtTime`.  So in `stopTone` include something like:

`inst.osc.stop(context.currentTime + 0.1*10)`

where the 0.1 is the time constant value used in `setTargetAtTime`.

This will stop the oscillators so they don't suck up all the CPU playing out to a zero-gain gain node.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this info! However, I'm not sure I follow the part about stopping the oscillators. The problem is that stopping the oscillator means it must be re-created to "restart" it. (That's why I'm leaving them running.) As far as I can tell, this gets into dynamically creating them each time (ie: dynamic variable creation). Can you offer some coding solutions as to how to do that?

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to do.  If you have a set of oscillators that should always being playing because you'll change the gain at some later time, then you're fine.  If you're doing something like a synthesizer, then you definitely want them to stop and recreate new ones as needed.  Don't know what the right answer is because you don't say what the application is.

Comment: I'll rephrase the dynamic oscillators for another time. You answered my main question. Thanks!